# How to properly use a secret from the Secret Manager in a Cloud Run deployment via gcloud shell

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I am trying to build me a gcloud script to deploy my cloud run service. This service has access to a hosted MongoDB and therefore I have to provide the password credentials via environment variable.

I'd like to pass this password via a secret manager. I do it via the GCP Console like so:

[image]

So the secret name is `mongodb-password` and the value `mypassword`. Now I follow the *gcloud run* documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy) to figure out how I can add the secret to the run service deployment.

In the section for setting a secret the following is explained:

> Specify secrets to mount or provide as environment variables. Keys
> starting with a forward slash '/' are mount paths. All other keys
> correspond to environment variables. The values associated with each
> of these should be in the form SECRET_NAME:KEY_IN_SECRET; you may omit
> the key within the secret to specify a mount of all keys within the
> secret. For example:
> '--update-secrets=/my/path=mysecret,ENV=othersecret:key.json' will
> create a volume with secret 'mysecret' and mount that volume at
> '/my/path'. Because no secret key was specified, all keys in
> 'mysecret' will be included. An environment variable named ENV will
> also be created whose value is the value of 'key.json' in
> 'othersecret'. At most one of these may be specified

This is somewhat confusing me. I have no idea what is meant by the **KEY_IN_SECRET**.
The secret name is obviously `mongodb-password` but I don't know how I can now refer to the value of the secret.

I tried to figure out if there is a convention on how to define the secret values. Maybe something like `key=value`. But nothing states I have to do it like that.

So now I wonder what I should do for the `--set-secrets=[KEY=VALUE,…]` flag for the `gcloud run deploy` command.

From the information given I only can do it like this:

```
--set-secrets=[mongodb-password=*]
```

which I know is wrong but I want to explain what confuses me at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused and it's normal. The secret manager integration is, for now, only available for Cloud Run on Anthos (for instance, deployed on GKE cluster).

If you use the fully manage version, Cloud Run not yet support secret manager integration (Alpha version should start soon, you can expect a public rollout later in the year).

So you need to get your secret directly in your code. Or, I created a wrapper to help you to [load the secret from secret manager and to set them in environment variable](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secret-manager-improve-cloud-run-security-without-changing-the-code-634f60c541e6).

---

In GKE, the secrets are described in the [Kubernetes secrets documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). You can mount a secret in a path in the linux dir tree `/path/to/mysecret`. It's a best practice and it should be the same thing with the fully manage version (to ensure the portability and the Knative compliance).

That's why you can stuff like this in the documentation `--update-secrets=/my/path=mysecret`